# Ruby parser to separate text from titles

Tags: ruby

I'm struggling around a Ruby parser.

I have a block of text with some titles. 
The text is free, without tags, the titles are wrapped between

Something like this

```
<h3>Title</h3>content content content <h3>Title</h3> content content content
```

I want to parse this text to populate an array of hashes with this structure

```
[{title : "title", content: "content"}, {title : "title", content: "content"}, ... ]
```

I need only an hint, I will try to find solution by myself. Is there any method that doesn't need Regex? I'm not so good in regex...

Comment: Please give us correct HTML.

Comment: I parsed it using Sanitize gem and I keep only title. Do you think is better to keep also <p> tag?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I check, the html is too dirty. A lot of nested div. I must clean everything if I want to obtain plain text...

Comment: If your input is HTML, use Nokogiri to parse it. Also your question is a little vague. Please, clarify the expected input. Is it HTML, is it something else with HTML tags inside?

Comment: @Michael my input is HTML of course, but is a very dirty html. I have inline styles, empty div, iframe, etc etc.

I'm writing a web to print application, I must clean the HTML to obtain plain text and so I'm using Sanitize that strip everything. The best result is a text with the pattern described above, paragraph with no tag separated by titles with <h3> tag.

Comment: The html and the hash below doesn't seem to have similarities, however you might give nokogiri a shot, you don't need to sanitize the html with nokogiri, you can just navigate the xpath

Comment: I will try with Nokogiri

Comment: I think Nokogiri is overkill. You will have to navigate the xpath, which is not part of what you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your regex:

```
   /<h3>(.*?)</h3>(.*)/
```

Run it for every line, $1 is your title, $2 is the paragraph.

Comment: this is my raw content to parse [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7846829/raw/658d050aa6f4fc09b9f5f05699f433844d4b7077/gistfile1.html).
As you can see is not so easy... Now I add <p> tag and I will try with Nokogiri...